# Corda 3 deployNodes - Node in Notary exited with 1 when generating its node-info

Tags: corda

I am trying to run the Example CorDapp (https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example) on Corda 3. When I try to run the `./gradlew deployNodes` step, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':java-source:deployNodes'.
> Node in Notary exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs in [REDACTED]/cordapp-example/java-source/build/nodes/Notary/logs

* Try:
Run with --info and --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':java-source:deployNodes'.
    at ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node in Notary exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs in [REDACTED]/cordapp-example/java-source/build/nodes/Notary/logs
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$gatherNodeInfoFiles$future$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:136)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$gatherNodeInfoFiles$future$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:44)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:107)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:119)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22)
```

Why is the network failing to be created?

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by having the wrong Java version. Ensure your Java version is in-line with the requirements here: https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html#software-requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when old builds with old names were present in the cordapp. Looking at the logs at "/cordapp-example/java-source/build/nodes/Notary/logs/" will reveal which old node is causing problems.

Running `./gradlew clean deployNode` clears the issue.