# Exception while deploying nodes locally on a CorDapp - node-info generation

Tags: java, gradle, jvm, corda, gradlew

I'm trying to run the sample cordapp described [here](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-the-example-cordapp-from-the-terminal)

The problem is that I am unable to deploy the nodes when I run the `gradlew.bat deployNodes` command. I'm repeatedly getting the following error:

> Node in Notary exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs

Some information about my environment

> Corda Version: v3.2
>   Gradle Version: 4.4.1
>   Java Version: 1.8.0_191
>   OS: Windows

The output when I run the command with the `--stacktrace` flag is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node in Notary exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs in C:\dev\cordapp-example\build\nodes\Notary\logs
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$gatherNodeInfoFiles$future$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:137)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$gatherNodeInfoFiles$future$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:45)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:107)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:119)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22)
```

Also tried to run `java -jar corda.jar -Dcapsule.log=verbose` from the notary node folder and got the following:

```
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: Illegal char <"> at index 0: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191 (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
USAGE: <options> corda.jar

Actions:
  capsule.version - Prints the capsule and application versions.
  capsule.modes - Prints all available capsule modes.
  capsule.jvms - Prints a list of all JVM installations found.
  capsule.help - Prints this help message.

Options:
  capsule.mode=<value> - Picks the capsule mode to run.
  capsule.reset - Resets the capsule cache before launching. The capsule to be re-extracted (if applicable), and other possibly cached files will be recreated.
  capsule.log=<value> (default: quiet) - Picks a log level. Must be one of none, quiet, verbose, or debug.
  capsule.java.home=<value> - Sets the location of the Java home (JVM installation directory) to use; If 'current' forces the use of the JVM that launched the capsule.
  capsule.java.cmd=<value> - Sets the path to the Java executable to use.
  capsule.jvm.args=<value> - Sets additional JVM arguments to use when running the application.
```

I'm really confused and any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if clearing your build folder works (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383934/corda-3-deploynodes-node-in-notary-exited-with-1-when-generating-its-node-info)

Comment: @user123959 I have already tried running gradlew clean deployNodes but it did not work

Comment: sometimes there may be a demon java process running. try killing that and trying. `taskkill /f /im java.exe` and then do a `gradlew clean deployNodes` and see if it works.

Comment: @Kid101 still didn't work. Getting the same error

Comment: try with JDK 8_181

Comment: @Kid101 didn't work with that either

Comment: Did you try opening the notary log file and seeing if any clues are there? Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606168/capsule-exception-while-deploynodes-task/51615379

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of fiddling around I managed to find the root cause.

The issue was with the `PATH` environment variable. It contained the values inside double quotes.

That was causing the Illegal char " at index 0 exception when I was trying to run the `corda.jar` file from the node folder.

Once the quotes were removed, it worked fine.